# How to install gromacs on gcp HPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cluster-computing, hpc

I am trying to install Gromacs, But havent found any method till now. I want to install it on GPU enabled cluster. Have tried using the official document which is present in gromacs official site. But facing some compiler error related to python.

https://manual.gromacs.org/current/onlinehelp/gmx-cluster.html

Have installed HPC instance using the below link.

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/hpc?hl=en

have not faced any issues coming to HPC but facing errors while installing gromacs software.

Can anyone help me in this.